# Insert c# into inline javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

Is it possible to insert a c# variable into a inline javascript function?

I'm using razor to pass the select boxes id.

```
<select id="@itemid" style="float:right" class="input" onchange="window.location.href='@url3' + 'booking/' + '?d=' + 'this.form.@itemid.options[this.form.@itemid.selectedIndex].value">
</select>
```

The above does not work. I get a "does not contain a definition for 'form'" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use Razor syntax in javascript as long as it is in the view file.

I prefer to keep the markup clean without the behavior(separation of concern) and keep that behavior in unobtrusive javascript way. I would keep a HTML 5 ***data attribute*** to set the value of `url3` variable.

```
<select id="@itemid" style="float:right" class="input" data-targeturl="@url3">
</select>
```

and in javascript, listen to the `change` event of SELECT element with `.input` class and redirect to the new page

```
$(function(){

 $("SELECT.input").change(function(e){
   var _this=$(this);
   var newUrl=_this.data("targeturl")+"/booking?d="+_this.val();
   window.location.href=newUrl;
 });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
onchange='@("string.format("window.location.href='{0}' + 'booking/' + '?d=' + 'this.form.{1}.options[this.form.{1}.selectedIndex].value", @url3, @itemid))'
```

Comment: The explicit expression block is missing a closing ")" character. The function above works ok, inline would have been nice.